# How can I send e-mail alerts from Sharepoint 2013 Calendar

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-calendar, sharepoint-email

I've just created a SharePoint Calendar with a couple of overlays which are working fine.

I'm trying to get it so that when an appointment is added to the calendar an alert is sent to e-mails X@123.com, Y@123.com and Z@123.com

How can I do this? I've had a look around but can't seem to see anything on it...

Thanks in advance - Please let me know if you require anymore details

Comment: you can do it with OTB alert me feature, via workflow, or using 3rd party alerting/reminder tool (f.e. JungleBell http://www.enovapoint.com/sharepoint-alerts-reminders/ )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue by providing access through User Management to the DL and it gave me the option to type into the "USers" box like in the screenshot provided by Rohit which is what i was missing before!

Thanks for the continued support with this :)

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this functionality using Alert Me. following are the steps.

1: Go To your Calendar

2: Go To "Alert Me"(on Ribbon) --> Set alert on this list

[image]

3: Configure your alert.

[image]

4: Done

Comment: NOTE: Users that are suppose to receive email should at least have read access for this list (Calendar).

Comment: Hi Rohit,

I can manage to get the alerts to send to me but i cannot unfortunately get them to send to multiple e-mail address or a DL which is what I need

Any ideas?

Comment: @Alex you can directly specify "DL" in Users. And "DL" should at least have read permission for the calendar. Please let me know if it is working for you.

Comment: Unfortunately i'm still not able to. I have tried to add a single user to the alerts who has read access to the calendar but cannot add them. I can only set them up for myself - See image below.
http://tinypic.com/r/nqm3p/9

Answer (score 0):

You can configure `Alert me` on calendar using `Alert me >> Manage My Alert` from Events tab in Ribbon.

Comment: Hi 

I can get the alerts to send to me no problem but i need to be able to send the alerts to multiple people when they occur - This is what i'm having trouble doing.

It isn't feasible to get them to set up an alert on their accounts for it either due to the number of people this will impact

Comment: yes, you can add multiple users in Alert me action

Comment: I dont get the option to, unfortuantely. The screenshot posted by Rohit shows that he can although I don't seem to be able to - AS per screenshot in this link - http://tinypic.com/r/nqm3p/9 - Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please attach your screenshot? So i can identify issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can create SharePoint designer workflow to run on new item added and include action "Send an email" . When ever new appointment is added , email will be sent to desired email address.