# How to create calendar notification e-mail?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-addin

I want to create calendar and when someone click on "Add" after filling all the details, it should email to a person.

How to add the email?

Comment: You can create a SharePoint Desinger Workflow which runs after item creation. Just add an action "Send E-Mail" with the details you want to have. How to create your first workflow is shown here: https://afrait.com/blog/how-to-create-your-first-2013-workflow-de-en/

Comment: Can we do without SPdesigner

Comment: You want to send an email when a new CALENDAR is created, or when a new EVENT in a calendar is created?

Comment: when a new event is created in the calendar

Comment: There are a lot of 3rt party alerting solutions for that, f.e. the easiest one - JungleBell from enovapoint http://www.enovapoint.com/sharepoint-alerts-reminders/

Comment: Similar kind of question is asked before. Refer this link- https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/181026/how-can-i-send-e-mail-alerts-from-sharepoint-2013-calendar/181053#181053

Answer (score 1):

You can set an alert to send mail to that person when new event is sent to that person.

[image: Calendar alert is available]

[image]

Comment: OTB "Alert me" is not available on calendar lists

Comment: Can we add person email in alert me

Comment: As Monica mentioned in the picture you can enter the name of the user in the column "Send Alerts To". Also you can type in the e-mail address of your choice.

Comment: I have done all the steps as mentioned when i click add and fill all the details and save i am not getting any email from the calendar. can help

Comment: May be email settings are not currently setup on the environment. Did you make necessary changes in Central Administration ?

Comment: yes i did all the changes

Comment: Try to check if alerts are working on another list. Also you can check ULS logs for more information.

Answer (score 1):

afaik there are two ways of doing this:

- Workflow;
- Event Receiver.

You may decide to put the email in a column of the list, in a configuration list, or in a property bag - depending on your requirements (e.g. if you decide to proceed with an Event Receiver and the email doesn't change often, i would choose the latter).

Since I understand you don't want to use SharePoint Designer, if I were you, I would proceed with an Event Receiver (using Visual Studio off course).

Remember that, if you are creating a Farm Solution and the email is a valid SharePoint user email address, you can use the [`SPUtility.SendEmail` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.sendemail.aspx).